# jQuery animate() function doesn't animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to program an animation in JavaScript and I'm having issues

In my program I'm trying to animate the `<label>`'s `margin-top` but it doesn't happen the way I want it.

e.g.

```
$('label').animate({marginTop: '0%'},500);
```

The `margin-top` css property changes but it happens in the blink of an eye rather than moving smoothly.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<label id="menu-button-label"><input type="checkbox" id="menu-button"></label>
```

JS:

```
$($('#menu-button-label').click(function() {
      if($('#menu-button').is(':checked')) {
            $('#menu-button-label').animate({marginTop: '0%'},500);
         }
  });
```

Comment: And does the element have a margin-top to begin with? jQuery needs a starting point for the animation

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/2h3qt60o/

Comment: like @FastSnail solved or do with toggle classes with transition :)

Comment: @adeneo yes it does have a margin-top which is set to 90%

Comment: Why are you applying the function to the label? If you click the input it will no do anything. Even if you check the input, margin will be on same position. Check the code of "gm-br". The script will only work if you click on the label. Doesn't care if checkbox is check or not. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in your code, but basically now I'm applying marginTop in one dive, and inside this dive have your label.

take a look the bellow code, I think will help you

```js
$(function(){
  //alert(3);
  $('#menu-button-label').animate({marginTop: '20%'},1500); 
  });

$('#menu-button-label').click(function() {

      if($('#menu-button').is(':checked')) {
            }
            $('.info').animate({ marginTop: '0px'}, 1000);
       
  });
```

```css
.item {
    background: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
 
}
.info{
    margin-top: 100px;
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <div class="info">
          <label id="menu-button-label">JS:</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="menu-button">
    </div>
  
</div>
```